# What is this None user in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts

What is this None user in Windows 8? It isn't one of my accounts. This is a question that is [ogooglebar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogooglebar).

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"None" is neither a predefined nor a builtin user. You can see a full list of wellknown security identifiers and their names at [MSKB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330/en-us).

Please use the old style user and group management tool `lusrmgr.msc` to check if a user or group with this name exists. [Here](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-8&faq=57) is a description how to start it. The simple user interface you used might filter out some accounts for any reason.

Another option is to run `net user` from command line (`cmd.exe`).

Comment: I started lusrmgr.msc, but it said "This snapin may not be used with this edition of Windows 8. To manage user accounts for this computer, use the User Accounts tool in the Control Panel."

Comment: @Chloe I added a hint to `net user`. Can you try that?